# How was the electron in Rutherford's model producing a continuous spectrum and not a line spectrum?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, history, spectroscopy

How was the electron in [Rutherford's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_model) producing a continuous spectrum and not a line spectrum? What is the logical thinking behind that it will produce a continuous spectrum?

Comment: It sounds like you think it should produce a line spectrum. Could you explain why? Otherwise people will probably not be able to clear up your confusion.

Comment: No it's not that. Actually the book I'm reading has not given reason and has just mentioned that it produces a continuous spectrum and not a line spectrum.

Comment: Well, Rutherford’s model was before quantum. Having a small positive nucleus with electrons ‘orbiting’ it was a problem that had to be solved, and quantum was the answer eventually.

Comment: The continuous spectrum of the orbiting electron at Bohr radius would have strong peaks at multiples of the fundamental frequency, it would not be a smooth featureless spectrum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Poynting vector you can derive/calculate the vector for both the accelerated charge and an electromagnetic radiation with a fixed frequency, i.e. a line spectrum. Or you can google them. The Poynting vector formula for accelerated charge is well-known as [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula). And for an electromagnetic radiation with a fixed frequency you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Plane_waves).
If you compare both, you'll see the Poynting vector of accelerated charge doesn't not have a well-defined frequency dependence, in other words, it radiates a continuous spectrum!

Comment: care to explain the down vote?